# No such signal QObject::aboutToClose()

Tags: c++, qt

Constant jumps from release to debug made me pay attention to the fact that when closing the release version of the application (opened directly in Qt Creator, before WinDeployeeQt), this is displayed in the console:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such signal QObject::aboutToClose()
```

although I do not use this signal and did not redefine it. I have only redefined this:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    ClearNotes();
    ClearClientOutputContacts();
    ClearClientRedactContacts();
    ClearContactOutputCompanies();
    ClearDocuments();
    ClearNewClientContacts();
    event->accept();
}
```

in which I clear all dynamic fields, if any. The question is, close your eyes to this or try to understand where this message comes from? (This is not present in debug mode, only observed in release mode).

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: @JarMan 6.3.0 version

Comment: aboutToClose is a signal in QIODevice: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#aboutToClose](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#aboutToClose) not QObject. I am not sure why a closeEvent() would be making  connect() call

Comment: @drescherjm i read about it, but i still don't understand what should i do.  Do not pay attention or still look for an error somewhere. Everything seems to be working correctly, but it annoys me.

Comment: It's probably harmless but at the same time could be important in the code depending on what operation was supposed to happen when whatever IO device it needed closed. Either way I believe the bug is in the application code you are running and not in Qt.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, man. In what direction should i  look where it is possible to find this error? If I insert qDebug() at the end of my closeEvent - then the above error will come out after qDebug.

Comment: @Mainquestion please provide a [mre]

Comment: In cases such as this I've often found it useful to install my own [`Qt` message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).  Then start your app under the debugger and set a breakpoint on the message handler.  When you hit the breakpoint the backtrace should give you some useful info. regarding the location of the erroneous `connect` call.

Comment: @G.M. message handler doesn't see this error :-)

Comment: Are you using QTextStream? That will internally connect to the QIODevice::aboutToClose signal. That this fails, and that `QObject::connect` prints `QObject::aboutToClose` instead of `QIODevice::aboutToClose` hints to the QIODevice being in the process of being destructed. Are you using QTextStream in a slot connected to some QObject::destroyed signal or such? (QNetworkReplyHttpImpl also connects internally to aboutToClose().)

Comment: @E4z9 yes, i am using QTextStream and close the file with close. What should i do this way?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing actual code. To me it looks like you possibly create a QTextStream, or call setDevice on a QTextStream in a QObject::destroyed handler of the device that you set on the text stream. E.g. I can reproduce your message with `{ QFile file; connect(&file, &QObject::destroyed, this, [&file] { QTextStream doc(&file); }); }`